# Virtual MIDI input device?

Tags: macos, audio, midi

Can I create a virtual MIDI keyboard that plays a `.mid` file?

I have the Piano VST *Addictive Keys*, and would like to be able to play `.mid` files using the sounds that this VST provides.

I thought I could use a virtual midi device as the input device for Addictive Keys.

Comment: What host are you using the VST in?

Comment: @CL. I don't know what that means

Comment: How are you currently using the VST? (Are you using it at all?)

Comment: @CL. plugged my keyboard into my macbook

Comment: There are drivers that create virtual MIDI ports, but you could use a VST MIDI player instead.

Comment: @CL. what's that?

Comment: [VST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology)

Comment: @CL. you're being very unhelpful

Comment: Are you asking about the VST architecture, or what a VST MIDI player is, or what a virtual MIDI port is?

Comment: @CL. How can I create a virtual MIDI instrument on my MacBook, so I can play .mid files through it and then use the instrument as input to Addictive Keys to get the Addictive Keys sounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to play a MIDI file with a VST plugin is to load it in some VST host (see [here](https://www.kvraudio.com/plugins/macosx/vst-plugins/hosts/free/most-popular) for a random list).

If you want to use a virtual MIDI port, you can [create one with the IAC driver](https://hearandknow.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/iac-get-virtual-midi-ports-on-a-mac/).

Comment: Nice, I was after the [IAC driver](https://hearandknow.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/iac-get-virtual-midi-ports-on-a-mac/). Now I can send synthesia output to IAC, and use IAC as Addictive Key's input.